# Change the default view setting for Explorer in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-explorer

How do you make a system-wide change to the view settings in Windows Explorer? It seems every folder needs to be changed to the view setting desired.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the folder with the view you want,

- Go to the *View* tab of the ribbon
- Click the *Options* button on the right hand side of the ribbon
- Select the *View* tab
- Click the *Apply to Folders* button.

If the *Apply to Folders* button is greyed out it could be that the view is currently in one of the following folders that can't have its view applied to all folders. **Computer**, **Favorites** or **library** folders.

Comment: Doesn't work on Win 8.1 since the "Apply to Folders" is greyed out.
For some reason, folders with pictures show up with Explorer view settings for music (track, album etc). This is a pain.

Comment: @Peter, I adjusted the answer to include a note regarding _Apply to Folders_ being greyed out. I'm unsure if it is what you are experiencing or it truly is a Windows 8.1 issue.

Comment: I agree with @Peter . This is very annoying 8.1 issue.

Answer (score 0):

### More clear answer, Step 2 is missing in the other step

1. Open Windows Explorer or any folder
2. Change your view to "list" or "details" or any other option
3. Click the Tools menu item
4. Click Folder Options...
5. Click the View tab
6. Click the Apply to All Folders button
7. Click the Apply button (lower right of window)
8. Click the Ok button